# Executing a function at the end of a countdown timer from a database

Tags: javascript, ajax, express, mongoose

I'm looking to create a countdown timer on my server which will be visible on the front end. Multiple clients will connect to the site, so regardless of what time they connect, all the times need to be in sync and on the same count.
At the end of the timer I want a function to execute on the backend, for sake of example lets just say a console.log

The length of the countdown will be stored in a mongodb database and so any info I send to the front end will probably have to be through an ajax request.

```
    startTime: {
        type: Number,
        default: 180
        // 3 minutes in seconds
    }
```

How can I create a countdown on the backend and continuously update the view so that the users can see each second that elapses? and once that timer finishes, how can run a function on my server?

apologies if my explanation is a bit shit, I've not been programming for very long and it's one of the first times I've really ever asked a programming related question online - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an endpoint that will give you the current time.
2. Set an interval in the front end, and GET that endpoint every so often.

Example -- this is just pseudocode in JavaScript (pretend the endpoint in your server already exists):

```
function pingCurrentTime() {
    setInterval(() => {
        http.GET('/current-time').then(data => {
            document.getElementById('current-time').innerText = data.currentTime;
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

And you can call the `pingCurrentTime` function on page load or whatever. Also, if you are doing server-side rendering you can render the page with the proper current time the first time around so everyone that requests the page will get the correct time, and it will begin pinging every second to get updates.

Comment: ahh okay, thank you. I'll give it a shot.
appreciate the response.

Comment: Sure thing. Feel free to accept the answer if it helps you so others with similar problems can see it.

Comment: If you want a more elaborate answer, please provide your server language and your UI framework, if any, and I can mock something quick up. But the example I showed is really all you need here to achieve what you want.